# How to train Keras models evenly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have a Keras model, which consist of several identical(between each other) smaller models. Like in the picture.

[image]

You can vary number of inputs to get predictions for different structures.
So basically I need to train 2 models (in my case) with different datasets concurrently.

code:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Add

input_array1 = []
output_array1 = []
hidden1 = Dense(64, activation='tanh')
hidden2 = Dense(64, activation='tanh')
output = Dense(1, activation='linear')
# first model
for i in range(14):
  input_layer1 = Input(shape=(52,))
  hidden1_i = hidden1(input_layer1)
  hidden2_i = hidden2(hidden1_i)
  output_layer1 = output(hidden2_i)

  input_array1.append(input_layer1)
  output_array1.append(output_layer1)

summation1 = Add()(output_array1)

model_1 = Model(inputs=input_array1, outputs=summation1)
# second model
input_array2 = []
output_array2 = []

for i in range(2):
  input_layer2 = Input(shape=(52,))
  hidden1_i = hidden1(input_layer2)
  hidden2_i = hidden2(hidden1_i)
  output_layer2 = output(hidden2_i)
  
  input_array2.append(input_layer2)
  output_array2.append(output_layer2)

summation2 = Add()(output_array2)

model_2 = Model(inputs=input_array2, outputs=summation2)

model = Model(inputs=[input_array1, input_array2], outputs=[summation1,summation2])
```

But when I train it, first model is training fast, but second slowly

[image]

I tried to change learning rate - doesn't help.

Is there any way to train them equally (worse loss on model 1, but better on model 2)
or just model itself can't represent several structures?

Comment: It is because of the weights initialization may be, put names into your layers, the other thing is to set the seed number of weight initialization and add regularization, not in both of them but the one whose lose isn't decreasing.

Comment: @MohammadAhmed but weights are the same between small models as they share layers, thus model 1 and model 2 has the same weights